# Problems with MAX( ) MYSQL call

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions, max

I'm having trouble using the MAX aggregate function in my PHO code.  What I'm trying to do is to select the highest user_id form my database. However, I get an error that says " Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: image_id not found in MySQL result index 3 " If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong with my code it would be greatly appreciated!

```
$highest = "Select MAX(image_id) FROM image_table ";
$result2 = mysql_query ($highest);
if (!$result2) die ("Database acces failed: " . mysql_error ());
$rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
for ($j=0; $j<$rows2; $j++)
    {
      echo 'highest image id: ' . mysql_result($result2, $j,'image_id') . '<br/>';
    }
```

Also, is there a way to set a variable directly equal to the highest id. Say for example i wanted the variable $maxID to be equal to  the current maximum id, which is 93...

Comment: What does your db structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Use an alias - `SELECT MAX(image_id) AS image_id FROM image_table ...`
2. Use an offset - `mysql_result($result2, $j, 0)`

Also, I would suggest switching over to PDO. Here's an example of that:

```
$db = new PDO( ... );
$res = $db->query('SELECT MAX(image_id) FROM image_table');
if (false === ($maxId = current($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)))) {
    // $maxId is definitely a number
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a way to set a variable directly equal to the highest id. Say for example i wanted the variable $maxID to be equal to 93...

Comment: @user1691618 I've updated my answer with an example of how I would do that in PDO

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I'm pretty new with php, and coding in general, and have yet learn about PDO's, so i'm not sure if I'll be able to understand your example, but I appreciate it.